# define quantity for each selected item in the same time

Tags: django, many-to-many, pos

i have tried a lot to get an answer for my problem , someone tell me if its possible please.
i'm working on a restaurant order management system , and apart of the system is a point of sale at the same time(for cashier) , when a customer visit to the restaurant , the cashier be able to fill a receipt,for example (3 pizza with 2 sandwich)

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product ,through='ProductOrder') 

@property
def total(self):
    return self.productorder_set.aggregate(
        price_sum=Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'), 
output_field=IntegerField()) )['price_sum'] 



class ProductOrder(models.Model):


    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE , 
    null=True,blank=True)
    ordering = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,  
    blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

#to make a new instance from order,but doesnt make! before saving 
#ProductOrder
def create_order(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    instance.ordering.save()


pre_save.connect(create_order,sender=ProductOrder)
```

forms.py

```
class ProductOrdering(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductOrder
        fields = ['product','ordering','quantity']
```

views.py

```
class ProductOrderCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ProductOrdering
    model = ProductOrder
    template_name = 'create_product_order.html'
    success_url = '/orders/'
    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.ordering = Order.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]

        return super(ProductOrderCreate,self).form_valid(form)
```

if the signal(pre_save) worked fine and after select a product,creating another field automatically(not formset) it will solve the problem
i asked alot everywhere but still not solved , please someone help me out i much appreciate

Comment: I don't understand what exactly are you trying to save here, can you explain it better. Thanks.

Comment: before creating a new instance from ProductOrder , it required to fill ordering field (its a foreign key) , create a new instance of Order then ( form.instance.ordering = Order.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]) to get the last Order instance , if not we must select ordering field in ProductOrder manually , i dont want do it

Comment: Okey share the ProductOrdering form please.

Comment: class ProductOrdering(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = ProductOrder
  fields = ['product','ordering','quantity']

Comment: @Hagyn is there any solution ?

Comment: Please fix indentation

Comment: its not the problem @jpic

Comment: It's a problem for readability

Comment: fixed indentation

Answer (score -1):

i think this is not specific to django problem, this is logical problem, so for me i will create an API endpoint to create "order", so from frontend send payload with identifier where will be store on db, what i mean identifier here is every "order" has 1 unique stuff so even customer order 3 items that item will be identify by their identifier.

Comment: can you explain more please , or show example of the code

Comment: Sorry i don't have example code, but maybe i can explain it.

First of all you need to learn about API first and of course frontend too.

`payload = {"identifier":"unique stuff", "items":[{"item_name":"name of item 1","quantity":324},{"item_name":"name of item 2", "quantity":324}]}`

So payload will be send from frontend to backend and then on the backend just iterate every items and save it to db with identifier, maybe you can create 1 models to save identifier and foregin key to every items ordered

Comment: how to implement this kind of payload